# Tratar erro: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'value' undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá,

Ao fazer uma requisição AJAX, tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of 'rede' undefined.
```

Até entendo o motivo, eu não tenho o seguinte valor por conta do filtro feito pelo usuário não retornar resultados na hora de carimbar os valores dentro do código, porém é possível tratar este erro? Tipo, colocar um `0` ou algo do tipo apenas para não interromper a leitura do restante do meu código?

Esta é a minha requisição, note o console.log tentando visualizar o retorno e como o console retorna o log:

```
$("#botao-filtrar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val(), codLoja: $("#dropdown-loja").val(), mes: $("#dropdown-mes").val()},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data[1]['rede']);   
        }
    });
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Por padrão, `data` é um array que tem uma extensão `3`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas as vezes, dependendo da opção selecionada pelo usuário, só retorna uma ou duas chaves por não possuir dados para mais uma chave.

Segue exemplo:

E aqui está o `PHP`:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('../../includes/gestaoOriginacao.php');

    $rede = $_POST['rede'];
    $codLoja = $_POST['codLoja'];
    $mes = $_POST['mes'];
    $nomeCompleto = $_SESSION['nomeCompleto'];

    $dados = array();
    $query = retornaQueryGrafico($rede, $codLoja, $mes, $nomeCompleto);

    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $query);

    while($valores = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
         array_push($dados, $valores);
    }

    echo json_encode($dados);

    function retornaQueryGrafico($rede, $codLoja, $mes, $nomeCompleto){
        $hierarquia = $_SESSION['hierarquia'];
        if($hierarquia == 1){
            $query = "SELECT * FROM evolucao_originacao WHERE redeTratada = '{$rede}' and codLoja = '{$codLoja}' and mesReferencia = '{$mes}' and supervisor = '{$nomeCompleto}' order by mesReferencia";
        } else {
            $query = "SELECT * FROM evolucao_originacao WHERE redeTratada = '{$rede}' and codLoja = '{$codLoja}' and mesReferencia = '{$mes}' and supervisor = '9999999' order by mesReferencia";
        }
        return $query;
    };
```

Comment: Coloque o valor de `data` por favor.

Comment: Ao invés de `console.log(data[0]['rede']);`, não deveria ser `console.log(data.rede)`?

Comment: Posta o `datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php`, o problema é nele.

Comment: tentei explanar um pouco como vem o resultado da requisição

Comment: Edita a imagem e mostra as chaves abertas (ou copia e cola do console aqui que é mais facil que imagem), assim saberemos qual é o retorno.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento editei com imagens e censurei em alguns lugares por conta de possuírem informações confidenciais. Mas creio que seja possível visualizar a estrutura do objeto.

Comment: Faz assim apenas `success: function(data){
            console.log(data[1]);   
        }` e veja o que retorna.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ele retorna um `undefined`

Comment: @jvbarsou faz assim `success: function(data){ console.log(data, data[1]); }` copia o resultado e coloca no pastebin.com e cola o link aqui (apague os dados sensiveis, como telefones)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento ele retornou isso: `[] undefined`, sem extensão.

Comment: Se retornou `[]` é porque o resultado veio vazio. Então pode fazer um if assim `if (data.length) { popula os dados aqui }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pelo que entendi não é um erro do PHP, o que está ocorrendo é que provavelmente **dependendo** da consulta a variável `data` está vindo vazia `[]`, então basta fazer um IF para checar:

```
$("#botao-filtrar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val(), codLoja: $("#dropdown-loja").val(), mes: $("#dropdown-mes").val()},
        success: function(data){
            if (data.length > 0) {
                //Atualiza a tela
            } else {
                //Exibe um alert(); ou outra coisa que avise que não retornou resultados
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Não esqueça de adicionar o `"error":`, é bom para checar, pode trocar por .done e .fail também:

```
$("#botao-filtrar").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php',
        async: true,
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {rede: $("#dropdown-parceria").val(), codLoja: $("#dropdown-loja").val(), mes: $("#dropdown-mes").val()}
    }).done(function (data) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
            //Atualiza a tela
        } else {
            //Exibe um alert(); ou outra coisa que avise que não retornou resultados
        }
    }).fail(function (erro) {
        alert(erro);
    });
});
```

Comment: Muito obrigado @Guilherme, vou adaptar meu código para esta função, mas já executei alguns testes e é possível tratar da forma que você possibilitou! Obrigado!!!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode verificar se a propriedade existe, em caso negativo criar uma com um valor padrão:

```
success: function(data){
    // verifica se é undefined
    if (!data[0]){
        data = [{rede: ''}]; // seta vazio para a propriedade rede do objeto no array
    }
}
```

Comment: E se `data[0]` for um objeto com várias propriedades menos `rede`?

Comment: O erro indica que `data[0]` que está undefined, caso só rede não exista o retorno será somente `undefined` @jbueno. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jz32skts/)

Comment: Desculpe, mas isso não resolve o problema, o problema está no `datacenter/functions/filtraDashboardGeral.php`, tem que ver o que retorna, então é só corrigir no Js.

Comment: Na real eu só apontei o problema da sua resposta sem considerar a pergunta. Considerando a pergunta, sua resposta não faz sentido porque se `data[0]` é `undefined` não faz sentido procurar por uma propriedade dentro disso.

Comment: Concordo @GuilhermeNascimento, por este motivo também pedi para o AP mostrar saída. Pois mesmo caindo no success, talvez tenha algum retorno.

Comment: @LucasCosta sério, eu acho uma baita dor de cabeça responder o que não está claro ou não pode ser reproduzido, o melhor nesses casos é votar pra fechar, se não gera mais confusão que qualquer outra coisa. Fechamento não é deletar é apenas prevenir que uma pergunta ruim receba respostas e depois mude totalmente o sentido invalidando as respostas. Entende? Tudo tem um bom motivo pra existir no site.

Comment: Dei uma opção de tratar no js o erro, conforme o AP pediu na pergunta @jbueno, visto que o resultado `undefined` pode ocorrer com algum tipo específico de filtro. Mas o solução ideal é o que o GuilhermeNascimento propôs, tratar no PHP.

Comment: @LucasCosta, pensa comigo. **Cannot read property 'rede' of `undefined`.** -> **Não é possível ler a propriedade 'rede' de `undefined`"**. Quem tá **`undefined`** é o objeto pai de `rede`.

Comment: @jbueno, pensei. No meu pensamento o pai de rede é `data[0]`. Ou to viajando? :/

Comment: Sim! Isso mesmo. E qual é o sentido de buscar por `rede` dentro de `undefined`????

Comment: Nenhum motivo, falha minha :p